# Integration of VIP developed in VMM into my UVM testbench

Tags: verification, system-verilog, uvm

I have developed testbench using UVM methodology in system verilog for my whole system DUT.
I have a VIP procured, which is in VMM methodology in system verilog. How do I integrate this VIP (in VMM) into my UVM testbench?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ask your VIP provider for the UVM version of the VIP.
2. Ask your simulation vendor for a VMM to UVM integration package.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
Thanks for the suggestion. I cant get the UVM version of the VIP from the VIP provider now.
I think, the second option could be implemented. But my concern here is, once I get the VMM to UVM integration package from the simulation vendor, how do i use the same to integrate it? I did some searching over net, but could not find the method to integrated these two environments, once i get the required package from the simualtion vendor.

Comment: And i too found one more option, while i was searching over internet. That is to build a UVM wrapper around the VMM VIP. But again, not sure of how to do the building of such wrapper.

Comment: You can have multiple testbenches written in different languages or different base class libraries all independently communicating with your DUT. Pin-level wiggling over time is a well defined interface. But as soon as those independent testbenches need to communicate directly, that's where you need a good understanding of the methodologies - how they are constructed and synchronized - in order to accomplish that.